# Modifying Shared Libraries in Linux

Tags: linux, shared-libraries, elf

Is it possible to modify a shared library (.so) in Linux without getting its source code???

I know about LD_PRELOAD, but is that useful for functions that are used IN the shared library itself???

Is there a way to decompile/disassemble and then recompile/reassemble binary ELF files?

Comment: Not easily, no. What library? What are you trying to change?

Comment: A webkit shared library ;)
The shared library is a proprietary build of webkit, but it uses most of the same opensource functions. 
What I am trying to do is modify an internal function. This function is used to render text on screen. I would like to modify the text (for BiDi) before sending it to the framebuffer. I can build the same library from the opensource repo and add those modifications, but due it being proprietary (which means it has UNopensourced modifications), the only way I can see further is binary patching (or LD_PRELOAD if it supports it).

Comment: By the way, the rendertext function is ONLY called in the library and is not called externally.

Answer (score 1):

Modifying applications is difficult to get right even with all the available documentation, code and support. Attempting to modify an application in binary form, (presumably) with no debug symbols, without documentation (judging by the fact you don't have the code) is therefore a much more arduous and risky undertaking.

Application reverse engineering is difficult, but can be done given enough resources, determination, tools and knowledge: all of this hinges on having a sufficiently valuable goal.